# Dynamic use of sequential numbers in oracle

Tags: oracle, database-design

Let me explain this in the best possible way about the problem I'm trying to solve.

Our client wants a ticket system. This system has to provide a strict sequential number for every ticket. Every day the ticket numbers will be reset to 0. Also there is a service_id associated with the ticket, and, this is the tricky part, every service will have it's own sequential number. Of course, the services are highly variable, so having a different sequence for every one does not seems to be the best approach in terms of manageability.

Also, there are periods of time where the concurrency of new tickets is very high, so querying a max(ID) + 1 could be too slow for the speed goal they need (almost instant).

Any ideas? Sorry there is no code, I'm in the very beggining of the project and need to have a decent approach to this problem.

Comment: By strict sequential number do you mean that for any given service_id first ticket should always have id=1, second id=2 etc, i.e. you're not allowed to have gaps in ticket IDs?

Comment: Yes, no gaps. Always starting from 1

Comment: What if a transaction gets a ticket ID, but gets rolled back? What if a ticket is deleted? You will have gaps. Live with gaps. *The client doesn't actually need a gapless sequence.* Now it's your challenge to convince them of this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could be an approach:

Build a table like the following, to store the tickets used for each service

```
create tabe tickets ( service_id ..., ticket ..., date ...)
```

Use a procedure like the following to get the ticket number for a given service, and store in table the last number used for each service (pseudo-code):

```
procedure get_ticket( p_service_id IN ..., po_ticket OUT ...) is
    pragma autonomous_transaction   

   /* search the service_id to see if it's already used */
   begin 
       select ticket, date into vTicket, vDate from tickets where p_service_id = service_id
   exception
     when NO_DATA_FOUND then vTicket := null; vDate := null
   end

   if vTicket is null and vDate is null then
       /* the service never had a ticket */
       vTicket := 0
       insert into tickets values ( p_service_id, vTicket, sysdate)       
   else
       if vDate = sysdate then
           /* the service already had a ticket today, need to increment */
           vTicket := vTicket + 1
           update tickets set ticket = vTicket where service_id = p_service_id
       else
           /* the service already had a ticket, but before today; need to set to zero */
           vTicket := 0
           update tickets set ticket = vTicket, date = sysdate where service_id = p_service_id
       end if;
   end if

   po_ticket := vTicket
   commit
end
```

In this way you should be able to store the tickets used for each service for a given date, without scanning greater tables to search for the max value used

This must be completed somehow to handle concurrency, by using explicit `LOCK`, `FOR UPDATE` queries or any other way, depending on what best fits your need and you can/cannot do on your dataBase.

Comment: Beautiful, and a very nice throughput. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this would be to *calculate* sequential ticket ID on demand instead of storing it. Let's say your table looks like `tickets (id, service_id, ticket_date, other_columns)`. Use a single sequence for `id`, don't roll it back, let it be the primary key. This way you don't care about gaps, transactions, whatever, Oracle handles it all for you.

Later, when you actually need a sequential number for a given ticket (let's say, with `id = :N`), use a query like this one:

```
select count(t2.id) from tickets t1, tickets t2
where t1.id = :N
and t2.ticket_date = t1.ticket_date
and t2.service_id = t1.service_id
and t2.id <= t1.id
```

Creating primary key on `id` and unique index on `ticket_date, service_id, id` should speed this query up considerably, even for large tables it would take a fraction of second to calculate the ID. You can wrap this up in a function and use it wherever you like, for example put it into view and query it as necessary.

If you need present all the sequential keys for a given service_id for a date, though, function can be too slow (though, test it first! Oracle can be amazing at working with huge data volumes). If it is to slow after all, you can use a view with a query containing analytical `row_number()` function, like this:

```
select row_number() over(partition by t.ticket_date, t.service_id order by t.id) seq_no,
       t.* 
  from tickets t
```

Index advice still applies for this one. Take note that you must include at least `ticket_date` when building queries against a view like this for it to get optimized by transformer and perform well - remember, `EXPLAIN PLAN` is your friend!